# How to use router in actions.js of vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

This is code from main.js where I`ve configured my router

```
enter code here
const router = new Router({
    routes,
    mode: 'history',
    saveScrollPosition: true
});


sync(store, router);

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App )
}).$mount('#app');
```

Then in vuex/actions.js I`ve action registerUser where I do request to API and if response is success I want to redirect user to main page

```
enter code here

export const registerUser = ({commit, state}, userData) => {
    commit(types.REQUEST_USER_REGISTER);

    api.register(userData).then(success => {
        const response = success.data;

        localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.token);

        commit(types.USER_OBJECT, response.user)

        //TODO: find better solution, then put router instance into window var
        window.router.replace('/');

    }, failure => {

    })
}
```

This code above works well, because I`ve set router instance into window var in build.js, maybe somebody know better solution instead of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move router declaration to separate file and export it. Then import in main file and any other file which you wish to use it. The api is the same as for `$router` property on vue prototype.